# Почему на stackoverflow люди часто отвечают не ответом, а комментарием? И как отвечать правильно?

Tags: поддержка, комментарии, ответы

Часто так бывает, что я задаю вопрос, мне отвечают комментарием. В итоге я не могу выбрать лучший ответ.  И когда сам хочу ответить на чей-то вопрос затрудняюсь выбрать между комментарием и ответом, как делать правильно в каких случаях?

В качестве примера приведу свой вопрос:
[Что означает, если процесс потребляет > 100% процессора в linux?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1098631/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-100-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2-linux)

Пользователь PotroNik ответил на него комментарием.

Comment: Какой смысл писать ответ, если он, например, будет простой цитатой из документации, которую автор почему-то не прочитал? Или, скажем, вся проблема - в тупой опечатке? Или в неправильном понимании сути термина, как в вопросе по ссылке? Подобные вопросы не так уж и редки. Опять же по формату SO - это QA, а не "всё подряд для чайников".

Comment: Мне обычно просто лень нормально оформлять ответ. А к неряшливому ответу тут же прицепится какой-нибудь "борец за чистоту расы", коих тут полным-полно

Comment: @avp e.g. insolor

Comment: @avp Но ответы по-моему когда можно все-же нужно писать. В коммент много кода и не загонишь...

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, если ТС заслуживает кода я пишу ответ

Comment: "В итоге я не могу выбрать лучший ответ". Напишите ответ на основе вашего решения проблемы, к которому подтолкнул вас комментарий.

Comment: в принципе суть я понял, спасибо всем за ответы

Comment: За комментарий не поставишь минус.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

комментарии должны использоваться только для (цитирую): "Используйте комментарии, чтобы получить дополнительную информацию или уточнить вопрос или ответ."

Comment: Спорный пункт правил