# Дублируется ссылка в тексте при переносе вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, перенос-вопросов

При переносе вопроса отображается вот такое сообщение:

> Этот вопрос был перенесён на [Stack Overflow на русском Meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10547), наш сайт для обсуждений, поддержки и предложений для этого сайта.
> [Перенесён](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) 1 минуту назад участниками [Qwertiy](/users/178988/qwertiy) ♦.

Косяк в том, что ссылка в скобках (которая, к тому же, отображается простым текстом) совершенно лишняя, поскольку предыдущая ссылка со словом `Перенесён` ведёт туда же.

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Поправил](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13860)

Был косяк в локализации. Лишний раз ссылка выводилась.